# Should a docker-ized Sinatra app have its source code in the container or in a mount?

Tags: docker, sinatra

I've researched numerous posts about dockerizing Sinatra, Rails, etc., but I'm not clear on where the source code for the app should best reside: in the container, or in a separate/external mount, for a production website?

I would think that the advantage of a separate mount would be that if the site's code is updated frequently, then one could I suppose just initiate an export of the code from Git to the mount, switch a symlink and maybe bounce the server somehow ...?  So the container would not have to be re-created and re-deployed, right?

Whereas with source in the container then one advantage I would think would be it's all self-contained and portable, if that is really an advantage?

I'd be interested in hearing people's pros and cons for this.

Our application is small, only used by a couple of people, and will rarely change.

Thanks

Comment: See if this helps in any way? http://tarunlalwani.com/post/deploying-code-inside-docker-images-statically-dynamically/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For local development it makes sense to mount an app dir and run it in your container. But for production I'd always put everything in the container. It's just messy otherwise. Begins with gem updates and so on. If you add the Gemfile first and run bundle update and then add the app files you will have a very lean build process that takes very little time to update. Combined with some automation it shouldn't be a problem for production apps. Gems will only update if the Gemfile changed.

Example Dockerfile:

```
# everything else
ADD Gemfile* $APP/

ENV BUNDLE_GEMFILE=$APP/Gemfile \
BUNDLE_JOBS=2 \
BUNDLE_PATH=/bundle

RUN bundle install  --without development test

ADD . $APP
```